# How can I store long value in .csv or Excel?

Tags: excel, csv

I want store the long value (`58585747483837484738474837`) in .csv or Excel but it displays in another format (`5.85857E+25`) even if the format cell is changed to text.

Comment: Put a tick (e.g. `'`) at the beginning as a [Range.PrefixCharacter property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.prefixcharacter.aspx) to force it into a text value.

Answer (score 0):

It's a feature of MS Excel. You have 3 options:

1. Switch cell format to Text, then enter desired value into formula bar, not into the cell.
2. Switch cell format to Number and enter value into the cell. It will suppress scientific notation, but may result in loss of accuracy for your long number.
3. Put a tick (e.g. ') at the beginning of the value, as mentioned in a comment (didn't know that myself).

Comment: As far as I know, you don't have to use the formula bar for entering numbers after changing the formatting to text.

Comment: No, it's still converted to scientific notation if you enter it in the cell. Just checked it in Excel 2013.

Comment: Funny, I just did the same thing in Excel 2013, and it doesn't get converted. Actually, that is how it should work. Do you use copy-paste or typing to get a huge number there? Because with typing, it is not supposed to matter if you use the formula bar or edit the cell directly.

Comment: Well, if you copy-paste, it overrides the pre-set formatting of the cell. So I'm guessing that is what you were doing. But even then, if you F2 or double click the cell to edit its contents, and then paste, the text formatting will be kept intact, and the number won't be converted. It only happens if you copy paste a number over the cell (without the cursor blinking in the cell or in the formula bar). But I think with regards to the original problem, this is irrelevant, as @Param didn't say he was copy-pasting values.

Answer (score 0):

It can only be stored as text. Excel stores numbers in floating point format. Basically it can store 15 significant figures (that means 15 consecutive non-zero numbers), and then the number of zeros before or after the number (maximum length around 308). See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel) for more info.

So if you want to store more than 15 different digits, it **has** to be stored as **text**. You can do this two ways:

- Add a ' (hyphen) before the number
- Change the cell formatting to Text **before** entering the value

Note that you won't be able to use these numbers in calculations!

If you want to use these numbers as numbers (e.g do some maths with them), you will need to format them as numbers. The Scientific format (e.g. 1,23E10) is just a formatting, you can freely switch between Number and Scientific formatting. Do note that if you use any **number** format besides text, your numbers will lose precision. For example:

1234567891123456789 will become 12345678911234500000

Hope this clears it up a bit.